# Generated prerequisite not triggering rebuild

Tags: makefile

I have the following Makefile:

```
.PHONY: version

OBJECTS = $(C_SOURCES:.c=.o)

%.o: %.c Makefile version.h
    $(call make_dir,$(dir $@))
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

version.h: version

version:
    $(PYTHON_EXE) build/version.py
```

`version.h` contains the current git commit hash. `build/version.py` updates `version.h`, if the current git commit hash is different (no changes if the commit hash is the same)

I want to run `build/version.py` everytime `make` is run, so version.h is always up to date. This is currently working, but if version.h changes my object files aren't being re-compiled. They get re-compiled the NEXT time I run make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `version.h` doesn't have an actual rule associated with it, and the other target tells make it builds `version`, not `version.h`.  So, make doesn't think that `version.h` was actually changed.

Give it a recipe, even an empty recipe, so make will understand it might have changed:

```
version.h: version ;
```

(the semicolon adds an empty recipe)